# PHP Includes & MySQL into webpage w/ Dynamic Variables

Tags: php, html

I Have a standard HTML table saved into a PHP file which I am putting on many webpages, but each webpage is about a different item.

So in my HTML table (in the blanktable.php file, which I include on the webpages) I've put in undefined PHP variables like so:

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>Item Name:</td>
    <td><?php echo "$name"; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price:</td>
    <td><?php echo "$price"; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    </table>
```

What would be the best way to dynamically create my webpages, so all I would have to do is define the variables instead of hardcoding the HTML each time?

Comment: Consider working through a basic PHP / mySQL tutorial: Many of them will cover this.

Answer (score 1):

You can load `$name` and `$price` from your database and then include your `blanktable.php`.
By this, the table will be filled with the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a mySQL database you would have something like:

```
    <table>
    <?php
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=1");
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Item Name:</td>
        <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price:</td>
        <td><?php echo $data['price']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must prepare the variables first, and then include the blanktable.php file for every separate item.

Get the products from your database with something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items";
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Then define the variable values and include the blanktable.php file for each item in your database table to display it.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $data['name'] = $row['name'];
    $data['price'] = $row['price'];
    include "table.php";
    }
```